# Clip Living Atlas layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, clip, living-atlas

Using ArcGIS Pro I want to clip this SSURGO soil hydrologic group layer https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=be2124509b064754875b8f0d6176cc4c

to a smaller layer in California for which I have a shapefile boundary. I am selecting the 'Clip Raster' tool but when I input the SSURGO raster layer I get the following error:

> Error 001491 Cannot process above the size limits of the image service: 'USA_Soils_Drainage_Class'. The allowed maximum number of rows and columns is 30000 and 30000 respectively. Please adjust the output extent and/or cellsize to fit within the limits.

I tried the Extract by Mask tool and I get the same error message.

I don't know how to proceed. Should I try to adjust the output extent? If so, how?

Comment: Web scraping is a TOS violation on many sites. I expect the Living Atlas folks would be willing to sell that data.

Comment: I don't think a violation. Toolbox for soil survey only works in ARC map so this seems like an honest workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a limitation of the webmap. There are probably a couple of alternatives to address this.

1. Do the data processing offline

The gNATSGO database, from which the California soil hydrologic group data you are looking for is derived, is available for download in its entirety. There are helpful GIS libraries available to help process individual layers within the database as well. You can see the full details here: https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/resources/data-and-reports/gridded-national-soil-survey-geographic-database-gnatsgo

Running the clip offline should avoid the limitation you are running into.

2. Tiled processing

You could generate subset regions of California that are small enough to avoid the limitation you are running into.

a. Using the California boundary as an input with the [Create
Fishnet](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/how-create-fishnet-works.htm) tool, generate polygons for your region.

b. Then use ArcPy to loop over each of the polygons in the fishnet and clip the raster to that region.

c. Finally, use the [Mosaic to New Raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm) tool to merge the clip result for each polygon from the fishnet.