# Error 001491 Cannot process above the size limit

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, image-service

So I have a high resolution ariel imagery for a whole county which I want to clip/split into a number of much smaller grids using `ArcGIS Pro 3.1`.

The issue is whenever I use tools like `Export Raster`, `Extract by Mask` and `Split Raster`, I get `error 001491` as shown below. Now, I can avoid this error by reducing the number of rows and columns but that reduces the raster resolution which I don't want.

Is there a way to avoid this error without having to reduce the resolution?

[image]

I did find a similar question, [Clip Living Atlas layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/452886/clip-living-atlas-layer), which doesn't really help because the `Clip Raster` tool returns the same error as well when I provide the high res ariel imagery as input.

What I don't understand is that I am able to add the imagery on the map and Pro loads/renders it just fine so why does it limit the user from clipping it while retaining the same res?

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer. But my guess is _no_ because the max row and column limit is a property of the service. If you own that service you should be able to increase it. Otherwise you're bound by these restrictions. Alternatively you could export a bunch of different areas and merge them back together?

Comment: Yup, you're are right, it's limited by service which we do manage.

Comment: Want to add that as an answer (and accept it as correct)?

Comment: @KHibma please add this as an so that I may accept it thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is a result of the max row and column limit defined in the service itself. These properties exist mostly to protect the service (server) from having to dispatch large quantities of data.

In your scenario, as you are both the owner and consumer of the service, it might be safe to increase these values as you'll be in control of how often requests will be made for what might be large amounts of data.

[ImageService properties reference](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/image-service-parameters.htm): **Maximum image size per request**

> The maximum number of pixel rows and columns that the server allows in
> a client request.
>
> If the client’s request exceeds this value, none of the pixels will be
> returned.